# iChat periodically disconnects

Tags: ichat

About twice a night, iChat will disconnect (though it'll still show me as connected).  After about 10 minutes, it'll realize it's disconnected and bring up a dialog telling me it lost the connection.  I can then close the dialog and reconnect with no trouble.

My computer's network connection seems to be fine throughout this.

Any idea:

- What might might be causing this?
- How to fix it?
- At least how to make it tell me more immediately when it loses the connection?

Comment: how are you connected to internet and server?

Comment: If you don’t rely on iChat specific features (Video/audio) I’d recommend you try adium (http://adium.im/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be your router loosing connection temporarily to your ISP.

I use [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/), an extension to iChat which, among other great things, auto-reconnects when connection is lost. Chax is donationware.

Comment: As I said, the network connection is fine- I kept ping running in a terminal window and saw no loss in connection.  If it's a network issue, it'd have to be for less than a second (or affect only Aim traffic).

Chax I will check out, though.

Comment: Doesn't work on Lion though